# Looking for a politically speculative story about California that I heard adapted on the radio

Tags: story-identification, podcast

The story was on a public radio podcast of some kind (maybe studio 360 or To the Best of Our Knowledge). It's set in California in the near future. That state has broken down so that there's more or less a war between left-leaning, pro gay, racially diverse, lesbian collective in SF/Berkeley and the conservative, religious rural areas.

A family from the countryside (I think husband is a truck driver) gets in financial trouble and moves to the city. The people there are friendly and helpful, but the husband soon resents their political leanings & feels emasculated by his uselessness. He leaves and I think joins a paramilitary group on the opposite side.

Does it sound familiar to anyone? I think it's pretty recent.

Comment: I'm got a feeling I've read this, but I can't think of the title or anything useful about it.

Comment: What about this story is fictional?

Comment: How does the husband join a lesbian collective?